# Angularjs event firing in chrome and firefox, but not in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I've got some problems with events in Angularjs. So I have an `event` in `SomeCtrl` implemented like this.

```
    $scope.$on('event', function () {
       // some logic
    }
```

When I'm debugging in Chrome and Firefox, then debugger stops on breakpoints inside `$on`. But on IE, it doesn't. Someone knows, what can be, a solution to this?

EDIT:

I execute function like this where I want to fire event:

```
    function doBroadcast(eventName, data) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast(eventName, data);
    }
```

Eventname is good, I checked it with debugger. I'm using IE11 and when I'm checking on IE9 with compability mode, then event is firing. But on IE10 and IE11 don't. My Angularjs ver. is 1.0.8.

Comment: from where do you emit or broadcast it ?

Comment: I broadcast it from dataService, where I write my data to local storage. I'm broadcasting it via `$rootScope.$broadcast('event',data);`

Comment: could you showcase your code please and which version of ie you are facing the problem